# How to fix Redis "memory leak"

Tags: memory-leaks, redis, restart, dotcloud

I'm using a redis memory store on dotcloud but despite expiring keys its used_memory never drops back down again.  Using `flushdb` or `flushall` from redis-cli doesn't cause the used_memory to drop from it's ~20Mb.  I've had the same problem on RedisToGo.

Anyone know how am I managing to fill it up? and how can I avoid doing this?  Perhaps there are certain characters you shouldn't put into redis values or keys?  I'm using it with EM and resque from a heroku rails app.

Comment: Hi, I suggest posting the output of the INFO command to provide more information about your issue.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, I'm asking for my own edification: I know that many processes never release their memory back to the OS, but instead, just re-use whatever they've already allocated.  Does a redis process actually relinquish memory back to the OS?  Or does it just hold onto it for future use?

Answer (score 0):

Redis also has a `mem_fragmentation_ratio` (eg: 2.5), so using both values would likely lead to more accurate measurements. At very low `used_memory` levels (eg: near-zero) the fragmentation can be quite high, and to mitigate this you would need to stop/start the redis instance manually.

RedisToGo may be reporting *real* memory usage in this manner, as a combination of `used_memory` x `mem_fragmentation_ratio`.